# chemfig -- \charge writes into surrounding text

Tags: chemfig

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \par ggg jjj ggg jjj ggg jjj ggg jjj
    \par
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{A-\charge{90:5pt=\textcolor{red}{+}}{B}-C}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I separate the chemical formula from surrounding text?

I'm not looking for a `\vspace{}` answer, if I have to choose a suitable measure manually for every such instance. I'd like it to be automated.

Using `\Charge` instead of `\charge` disturbs the vertical alignment of A, B, C.

Putting the scheme into a `minipage` environment did not help.

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you start your line with `\par`? You should rather end the lines with `\par` or just put one empty line which means the same.

Comment: End of line, beginning of line: is there a great difference? And I don't mind the ```\par```, it feels to me like the Python saying "Explicit is better than implicit."

Answer (score 3):

A way to bypass `overlay` with `\tikzmarknode`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \par ggg jjj ggg jjj ggg jjj ggg jjj
    \par
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{A-\charge{90:5pt=\subnode{a1}{\textcolor{red}{+}}}{B}-C}
    \tikz[remember picture]\path (a1.north) ++(0,2pt);
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting method. But for me it doesn't work. My compilation has the plus sign in the text, and with every compilation it says „LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right."

Answer (score 2):

The [`chemfig` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf) (on page 32) suggests something like the following which, however, extends the bond between the atoms next to the charged one:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\definesubmol\X{\vphantom{X}}

\begin{document}
    ggg jjj ggg jjj ggg jjj ggg jjj

    \chemfig[anchor=atom.base]{A-!\X|\Charge{90:5pt[red]=+}{B}|!\X-C}

    ggg jjj ggg jjj ggg jjj ggg jjj
\end{document}
```

[image]

First, we use the `\Charge` command to add the plus sign. The `\Charge` command, unlike the `\charge` command, will not print the charge as `overlay`. Then, we define a submol `\X` that is essentially a box of zero width and of the height of the letter X. We append this "zero-width atom" to the left and right of the actual (charged) atom using `!\X`. We then need to split the atoms using `|`, so that the "molecule" now becomes `!\X|\Charge{...}|!\X`. This way, when `chemfig` connects other atoms to this molecule, it sees just an atom with the height of X and hence aligns everything vertically correctly.

--

If you want the bonds to have the original length, you can adjust this using the second argument of the bond options:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\definesubmol\X{\vphantom{X}}

\begin{document}
    ggg jjj ggg jjj ggg jjj ggg jjj

    \chemfig[anchor=atom.base]{A-[,.87]!\X|\Charge{90:5pt[red]=+}{B}|!\X-[,.87]C}

    ggg jjj ggg jjj ggg jjj ggg jjj

    \chemfig[anchor=atom.base]{A-\charge{90:5pt[red]=+}{B}-C}

    ggg jjj ggg jjj ggg jjj ggg jjj
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Good explanation! I didn't understand it so clearly, when I skimmed that section in the manual. Just not quite satisfied with the change in bond length.

Comment: @Wolfram It is in fact not that easy to understand. You can adjust the bond length manually, but it still feels a bit hacky.

Answer (score 1):

if you use \begin{center} \end{center} for the ChemFig figures there will be no overlap.

```
   \documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \par ggg jjj ggg jjj ggg jjj ggg jjj
\begin{center}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{A-\charge{90:5pt=\textcolor{red}{+}}{B}-C}
    \schemestop
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is like a ```vspace{}``` solution, because the ```center``` environment adds some space. With ```\charge{90:12pt``` the plus will be again in the text above the formula.

Comment: When Chemfig adds a sign using \charge, the sign may even be outside the figure if you are creating a "standalone" document. One possibility is to create images with Chemfig "standalone" format and insert them into the text as PDF figures.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you. It sounds possible (maybe cropping the image with pdfcrop), but quite complicated. Is there no possibility to do that within LaTeX?

Comment: Isn't necessary "crop", use \documentclass{standalone} \usepackage{chemfig} \begin{document} \chemfig{XXXXX} \end{document}   and use latexpdf to rum. you will create a PDF picture of the molecule.

Comment: pdflatex, not "latexpdf", sorry